# Perl error: Can't locate XFileConfig.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, apache, centos, perl-module, mod-perl

I'm trying to install a Perl script in my server. When I received Server access.

I installed apache2, mod_perl, activated mod_rewrite in var/www/html

when I try to execute install.cgi I get the following error:

```
[Wed Jun 20 21:09:36 2012] [error] Can't locate XFileConfig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /etc/httpd) at /var/www/cgi-bin/install.cgi line 4.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/install.cgi line 4.\n
```

I'm under Centos 5, Perl v5.8.8

Comment: Have you followed the install instructions which came with XFileSharing?

Comment: Yes, everything is uploaded in the right place, but install.cgi can't find XFileConfig.pm

Comment: Have a read through this http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/perl/perl-error-cant-locate-module-in-inc should explain how to add the instal location to the path the script is looking in for modules

Comment: What's the path to `XFileConfig.pm`?

Comment: @nickisfat: I already read the article

Comment: @ikegami: the path of the XFileConfig.pm /var/www/cgi-bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure that you have XFileSharing installed.
2. Locate the path where lib for XFileSharing are installed. You can
   use following command to locate XFileConfig.pm

   ```
   updatedb
   locate XFileConfig.pm
   ```
3. Add following line at top of your perl script.

   ```
   use lib '<path>';
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Check module is installed or not using `perl -MModule::Name -e "print 'OK';"`

Install using `cpan install Module::Name`.

Add path to `@INC`using httpd.conf

`SetEnv PERL5LIB "/path/to/directory/containing/module"`.

This adds path to `@INC` permanently.

Or

`use lib '/path/to/directory/containing/module';` in perl script which is using that module.

This is a temporary way and you will have to add it in every single perl script.

Or

`perl -I/var/www/cgi-bin install.cgi`

`-I` is used to include path while running install.cgi.

Ex:

```
> perl -IC:\a\b -e "print @INC;"
C:\a\bC:/Perl/site/libC:/Perl/lib.
```